# How to create an Activity where I can draw on the screen, save the image, and transfer it to another drawable screen?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

Right now, I'm using a CustomView to draw on a canvas, where I need to save the canvas (perhaps as a bitmap) into a FileOutputStream, and move to another CustomView with the same functionality.

I'm not sure whether I should be using a different method to implement this, but whatever I'm doing is crashing as soon as I call startActivity(i).

My understanding is that my CustomView gets drawn on with onTouch(), which draws onto the Path object, and then calls onDraw(canvas), which draws the Path on the Canvas. (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Does this canvas contain a bitmap object? Or does every call to onDraw need to write to a separate bitmap, created during onCreate()? Or do I need to create a new temp bitmap for each call to onDraw()? I've seen so many different Q&As on this and haven't found understanding yet.

Here is my MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Bitmap pic;
CustomView mCustomView;
OnTouchListener touchListener;
Button eraseButton;
String [] files = { "File1.png", "File2.png", "File3.png" };

int color = Color.BLACK;

RelativeLayout layout;

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    mCustomView = new CustomView(this);
    //layout.buildDrawingCache(); should I use this?

    layout.addView(mCustomView);

    touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            }
            mCustomView.invalidate();
            return true;    
        }
    };
    mCustomView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.black:
          Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen " + getResources().getString(R.string.black) + ".",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          color = Color.BLACK;         
          break;
      case R.id.red:
          Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen " + getResources().getString(R.string.red) + ".",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
          color = Color.RED;
          break;
      case R.id.blue:
          Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen " + getResources().getString(R.string.blue) + ".",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
          color = Color.BLUE;
          break;
      case R.id.yellow:
          Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen " + getResources().getString(R.string.yellow) + ".",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
          color = Color.YELLOW;
          break;
      case R.id.erase:
          Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen to clear the screen. The current pen is now Black.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          color = Color.BLACK;
          path.reset();
          mCustomView.invalidate();
          item.setChecked(false);
          break;
      case R.id.next:
          nextScreen(); //saves the bitmap, and call startActivity(), crashing now
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
      item.setChecked(true);
      return true;
}

public void nextScreen(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(files[0], Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("filename.png", files);
    startActivity(i);
}

public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (pic == null){
            pic = Bitmap.createBitmap(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //is this correct?
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(pic, 0, 0, paint); //is this correct?
    }
}
```

}

Comment: put up the logcat of the crash

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna save the view, you should use `public Bitmap getDrawingCache ()`, see the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28boolean%29). Try to modify your code:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (pic == null){
            pic = Bitmap.createBitmap(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //is this correct?
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(pic, 0, 0, paint); //is this correct?
    }

public void nextScreen(){
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = mCustomView.getDrawingCache ();
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(files[0], Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("filename.png", files);
    startActivity(i);
}
```